# Do both parentheses and braces around expressions basically do the same thing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, brackets, curly-brackets

Simply put, are these two `for` cycles functioning the same way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (p_size < size ? p_size : size); i++);
for (int i = 0; i < {p_size < size ? p_size : size}; i++);
```

?

The loop is inside a method (member function), `p_size` is its parameter and `size` is an attribute (member variable). Microsoft Visual Studio 2015  compiles both codes, but `p_size` is not coloured like the other parameters (in the editor) in the code with the curly brackets.

Comment: The version with the braces does not compile with gcc 5.3. It is a non-standard, non-portable, Microsoft compiler-only compiler "feature", apparently designed to "embrace and extend" C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't act like Microsoft is the only compiler vendor "embracing and extending" the language, please. Even open-source compilers do it.

Comment: Oh, you happen to know any other compiler that allows you declare main as "void Main(array<String^>^ args)", and call _that_C++?

Comment: At first I thought the construct in the braces was a GCC ["Statement expression"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) language extension.  But I see that those have to be enclosed in parens and braces: `({ ...  })`.  Exactly what MSVC extension is this?  I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: MS calls `void Main(array<String^>^ args)` "C++/CLI" and they have an ECMA standard proposed for it. I don't use it or care much for it (I've not done any real.NET work in a long time, and when I do it's in C#), but one might consider it Microsoft extending C++ for NET in a similar fashion to how Stroustrup extended C into C++ for his purposes. I'm not saying that C++/CLI is a good language or a good idea, but extending an existing language for new needs is not without precedent. One good thing about C++/CLI is that any C++ programmer will immediately recognize it as "not C++".

Comment: @Stefan: Can you post an complete example including information about command line options/project settings?  I get a set of errors starting with `error C2059: syntax error: '{'` when I try to compile the example with the braces in VS 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is valid code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (p_size < size ? p_size : size); i++);
```

This is invalid code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < {p_size < size ? p_size : size}; i++);
```

Having curly braces in the middle of the expression like that is invalid.

I'd also in general recommend [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min):

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::min(p_size, size); i++);
```